# Table inside a div with border does not occupy full space

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to place a table inside a div. Div has its own border, but I also want border of the table. So I have set the border of td but i found the my table is not occupying full available space. Is there something that I am missing over here?

Here is the sample [implementation](https://plnkr.co/edit/PldyKf60e6Jey1In3lPy):

I am trying below mention code:

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.table td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
      padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>First</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>Second</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>Third</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated the editor but still i found separate border for div and table. Please check updated plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/PldyKf60e6Jey1In3lPy

Comment: you clearly haven't posted all of the relevant code and styling on these elements if your result is any different then the provided answers.  Why are you using `position:absolute` on your table? What is your `div` `display` style when you inspect it (using F12 - Web Developer Tools)?

Comment: In your question, you said "I also want border of the table ..." which does not seem right, and it does not reflect your code; for you are specifying a `bottom-border` on your cell and not specifying any border style on your table.

Comment: after looking at your Plunkr, I do not see your issue; However, I did note that you added `border-right: 1px solid black;` to your `.table td`.  Please update your question by providing a screenshot of what you're seeing; Tell us what browser you're using. Also, see if this issue is reproducible in other browsers/clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add [border-collapse:collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) to your table:

like this :

```
.table{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/html-viewer/638f1fcf5167).

Here is the full code :

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

.table td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>First</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>Second</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>Third</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated the editor but still i found separate border for div and table. Please check updated plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/PldyKf60e6Jey1In3lPy

Answer (score 3):

Pre HTML 5, add the following to your table as attributes:

```
cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0
```

For reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellspacing.asp

HTML5 requires css.

```
table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
th, td {padding: 0px;}
```

So for your case:

```
.table {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
 }

 .table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
 }
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/gtajLmqh/5/

Comment: I updated the editor but still i found separate border for div and table. Please check updated plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/PldyKf60e6Jey1In3lPy

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the extra space around the table cells by setting:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

It's set to `border-collapse: separate;` by default, read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse).

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse; /*NEW*/
}

.table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the editor but still i found separate border for div and table. Please check updated plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/PldyKf60e6Jey1In3lPy

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota Just remove the right border on the td see [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOobbN) demo.

Comment: If I remove that border then a blank gap will be displayed. I want to remove that.

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota There must be something else interfering, as the demo above works fine.